# how to generate the series 'a','a',1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11 using R technology with rep and seq functions

Tags: r

Below is the series need to get using R with rep and seq
series : 'a','a',1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11

```
I am Leaning R as beginner. Please try to help me on the above query
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this albeit not the best way:

```
myseq=c(rep("a",2),seq(1,5,1),seq(7,11,2))
```

Comment: Should be `seq(1, 5)` not `seq(1:5)` I guess. Although in this case it does not make a difference. But try `seq(2:3)`

Comment: Thanks,fixed that!

Comment: why the class is character?

Comment: You're combining numbers and strings. Otherwise,you'll get `NA`s

Comment: on top of that result i am converting as.integer(myseq). It is warning me with NAS. Why it is?

Comment: You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information If this answer produces your sequence, please accept it. Otherwise, wait for another answer.